# Do all MD5 hexadecimal hash representations start with a number?

Tags: php, md5

Whenever I hash a name of a file with MD5 (the file was just uploaded and given a MD5 hashed name) the hexadecimal representation of the hash always starts with a number.

Is this a coincidence of the few files I have on my server, or is this a normal case?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're looking at?

Comment: Don't confuse encryption with hashing. MD5 is a hashing function. What you see is a hex number, only problem is that we represent hex numbers with letters digits 0-9 and letters A-F so it seems that MD5 hash is a sequence of letters and numbers but it's not.

Comment: Yeah, an example would help. Are you asking about the actual "#" (octothorpe) symbol showing in the beginning, or a number (0-9).

Comment: Hashing (md5) doesn't equal Encryption, Hashing is one way, encryption is reversible.  (If I had a penny for everytime I read that...)

Answer (score 11):

```
chris@siri ~ (3.6M) $ echo 'yoyo' | md5sum 
e0ea852f2f2d9564429842f7863af499  -
```

it's a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is not part of the md5.. the whole md5 is 32 letters each representing 4 bits with one hexadecimal digit. Since the whole md5 is just hexadecimal digits, you could say it always starts with a number.

You might have meant if they always start with the hex digit 0-9 instead of a-f, then the answer is no. They can start anywhere between 0-f.

To wrap it up: [hexadecimal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Comment: This. The `#` character must come from somewhere else.

Comment: Confused. Where did OP say there is a # included?

Comment: @Bryan, someone vandalized the question. I'll rollback

Comment: @Esailija, the title of the question indicates the change was made to clarify the question, not to vandalize.

Comment: @FelixLoether, maybe it's not the right term but "#" was changed to "number"... maybe the OP's hashes are prefixed with "#", who would know if the edit "clarified" it ?

Comment: @Esailija, The title of the question is "Do all md5 encryptions start with a *Number*?" I think that makes it pretty clear which one the OP meant.

Comment: @FelixLoether, you are correct but it was initially confusing to us non-natives who don't use slang words like "#" for number :P It looks like the question meant to ask do the hashes always start with a 0-9 instead of the higher hex digits (a-f)

Answer (score 1):

`md5` is a 32-character hexadecimal number so it can start with a digit or a letter between `a` and `f`.

Answer (score 0):

the md5 can only be hexadecimal (32 digits 0-9 A-F), the hash is not part of it.

Comment: I think the intention was '#' as in 'number', not literal hash character.

Comment: This is a bit pedantic, but md5 is a hashing algorithm that returns a 128-bit *number*. Yes, the number is usually in hexadecimal, but nothing stops me from writing it in decimal, or binary, or however I want.

Comment: Right, though not very conventional, I think the hexadecimal thing is kind of an standard, like driving on the right. Something too arbitrary to argue with but clearly necesary to agree on...